# A closed formula for $A_n(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n X^{i^2}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

I want to know if there exists a closed formula for sum $A_n(X)=\sum \limits_{i=0}^n X^{i^2}$.

I have found if $n$ is odd then $(X^n+1)\text{ | } A_n(X)$, but I don't have found a closed formula.

Comment: The infinite series is a Jacobi theta function ... $$\frac{\theta_3(0,q)-1}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}$$

Comment: Just an idea for your second question. Let $n$ odd and let $\zeta^n=-1$. It is enough to show that $A_n(\zeta)=0$. Maybe, using the orthogonality relations for roots of unity in the expansion of $(1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots+\zeta^n)^n$, gives $A_n(\zeta)=0$.

Comment: I thought you had "found" and not proved your assertion. My bad. I factored your polynomial for small odd $n$ and it gives: small polynomials times a very large irreducible one (over the integers).

Comment: The generating function is $$g(X,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(X) z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty X^{n^2} z^n$$
This is related to Jacobi theta functions: $$(1-e^{it}) g(X, e^{it}) + (1-e^{-it}) g(X, e^{-it}) = 1 + \theta_3(t/2, X)$$

Comment: I try to say it better, if the series $A_n(e^i)$ is not bounded, then we can't have $A_n(X)=\frac{N_a(X^{n^2},X^n,X)}{D_a(X)}$, with $N_a$ and $D_a$ polynomials, like gemotric series where $N_g(X^n,X)=X \times X^n-1$ and $D_g(X)=X-1$.

Comment: $A_n(\exp(x))=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^jk^{2j}}{j!}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {k^{2j}}=...$ I don't know how continued

Answer (score 6):

Not at all an answer, just observations. Firstly, a conjecture, based on experiment.

**CONJECTURE** $A_{2n}$ is irreducible for all $n.$

(empirically true for all $n\leq20.$)

**CONJECTURE 2** $A_{2n+1}/(x^{2n+1}+1)$ has at most one non-cyclotomic factor.
(empirically true for all $n\leq 20$).

Finally, the roots of these things cluster around the unit circle (see the graphic for $A_{14}$).

Is it true that the zeros of the infinite series are on the unit circle?
(oops, this is not supposed to be a question).
[image: Roots of $A_{14}$]

Comment: Neat graphic.  There's a product formula (probably a special case of the "Jacobi triple product") that shows that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty X^{i^2}$ has no zero with $|X|<1$.  But $|X|=1$ is a natural boundary so it doesn't make sense to ask about zeros on or outside the unit circle.

Comment: $\left( \sum_{i=0}^n X^{i^2} \right) / X^{n^2}$ converges to $1$ for $|X|>1$, and this renormalized limit is certainly nonvanishing. Probably one can convert this to an explicit bound on the zeroes of the finite sums.

Comment: Re the second conjecture: $A_n/(x^n+1)$ is irreducible for $n=3,7,15,31$;
for other odd $n \leq 41$ it has at least two factors but sometimes has
three ($n=17,35$) or even four ($n=29,41$).  Still all but one factor
is cyclotomic; maybe that's what you meant to conjecture.  
[Also: "$<=$" $\neq$ "$\leq$" . . .]

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies You are absolutely right on all counts, I fixed the conjecture and the typo (the latter coming through alternating between programming and latex).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Presumably, if the product formula whereof you speak actually gives a lower bound on the infinite series in the disk $|z| < r < 1,$ it will imply at least a one sided clustering, and then something similar after $z\to 1/z$ will give the other side.

Comment: The "other side" is elementary as **Will Sawin** noted.  
Unfortunately the product formula I had in mind is for the 
two-sided sum $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty X^{i^2} = 2 A_\infty(X) - 1$.
The sum $A_\infty(X)$ itself does have at least the conjugate pair
of zeros in $|X|<1$ suggested by your plot, near
$-0.6701129 \pm .4274072i$ (you can get many more digits using
Newton's method), and might have infinitely many more.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes, I was mystified by your triple product commentary because of the two-sided vs one-sided issue, but am glad that I was not confused as much as I might have been. As for the pair of zeros, true.

Comment: Looking closer at your plot also suggests the zeros of norm $.96064+$ in the right half-plane near $0.5309172 \pm 0.8005987i$.

Comment: A bout the first conjecture, it the same case for $G_n(X)=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} X^k$ when n+1 is prime, but there are a closed formula.